# What's the common fast way of expressing the infinite enumerator `(1..Inf)` in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, enumerator

I think infinite enumerator is very convenient for writing FP style scripts but I have yet to find a comfortable way to construct such structure in Ruby.

I know I can construct it explicitly:

```
a = Enumerator.new do |y|
    i = 0
    loop do
        y << i += 1
    end
end
a.next  #=> 1
a.next  #=> 2
a.next  #=> 3
...
```

but that's annoyingly wordy for such a simple structure.

Another approach is sort of a "hack" of using `Float::INFINITY`:

```
b = (1..Float::INFINITY).each
b = (1..1.0/0.0).each
```

These two are probably the least clumsy solution I can give. Although I'd like to know if there are some other more elegant way of constructing infinite enumerators. (By the way, why doesn't Ruby just make `inf` or `infinity` as a literal for `Float::INFINITY`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [#to_enum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Object.html#method-i-to_enum) or [#lazy](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-lazy) to convert your [Range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Range.html) to an [Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html). For example:

```
(1..Float::INFINITY).to_enum
(1..Float::INFINITY).lazy
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about `lazy`. Seems to be a great way to better mimic FP principles.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally create my own Ruby class for this.

```
class NaturalNumbers
  def self.each
    i = 0
    loop { yield i += 1 }
  end
end

NaturalNumbers.each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

Comment: What if I wanted `def f(n); (1..1.0/0).each_with_object([]) { |i,a| a << i; return a if i*i == n }; end`? I think you need to return an enumerator if no block is present.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 2.7 introduced [`Enumerator#produce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-c-produce) for creating an infinite enumerator from any block, which results in a very elegant, very functional way of implementing the original problem:

```
irb(main):001:0> NaturalNumbers = Enumerator.produce(0) { |x| x + 1 }
=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Producer:0x00007fadbd82d990>:each>
irb(main):002:0> NaturalNumbers.first(10)
=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
irb(main):003:0> _
```

... which - if you're a fan of [numbered block parameters](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/doc/NEWS/NEWS-2.7.0#numbered-parameters-) *(another Ruby 2.7 feature)* - can also be written as:

```
irb(main):006:0> NaturalNumbers = Enumerator.produce(0) { _1 + 1 }
=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Producer:0x00007fadbc8b08f0>:each>
irb(main):007:0> NaturalNumbers.first(10)
=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
irb(main):008:0> _
```